# Get Background color using CSS in QTP

Tags: html, css, vbscript, qtp

[image]I am automating an application which has a status bar, and it moves forward(turns green) if certain things are accomplished. Now, I want to check that when I complete a task it turns green. QTP's Object spy is not displaying the Color property and simply writing getroproperty("color") is not working as well. So I am trying to use CSS in QTP to achieve it. Following is my code-

```
  set a = Browser("name:.*").page("title:=.*")
   'here it highlights the correct part of the status bar
   a.Webelement("css:=.progress-bar-success").Highlight
   color = a.Webelement("css:=.progress-bar-success").GetROProperty ("background color")
   msgbox color
   'but the above msgbox returns a blank value
   'if i replace the 3 rd line with the following 
color = a.Webelement("css:=.progress-bar-success").GetROProperty ("style/background color")
```

Then it returns a constant rgb value of (92,184,92) even for other records where no progress is made. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `.Object` on the web element, it should expose all the native methods of the object, might be helpful?

Comment: @DAVE color property is not mentioned in the HTML itself but in the linked CSS. I have attached an image.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing the Webelement properly try below line, it should work:

```
a.Webelement("css:=.progress-bar-success").Object.style.backgroundColor
```

Comment: Tried, its still coming as blank. I am pretty sure its the correct web element as QTP highlighting only the green part of the bar. I will keep trying with {.object} though.

Comment: On a second thought the color property is not mentioned in the HTML itself but in the linked CSS, so I am not sure writing object will help. I have attached a image for the Html.

Comment: Hi, looking at the screenshot of your HTML it looks like your site uses Bootstrap(even I found that on researching after looking some of the field values) but what I think is happening is your background color never changes it just hides some width of div or so to make it look like its progressing


So instead of checking the color which will not change youcan use the aria-valuenow to find the current status of the bar for eg.

`Browser("...").Page("...").Webelement("...").Object.getAttribute("aria-valuenow")`
 ... if this value is 100 it should be that progress bar is complete

Comment: its returning null every time, even aria-valuemin and max are returning null. Just to be sure that I am accessing/identifying the right web element(even QTP is highlighting it), I used .GetAttribute("class") and it returned the correct  class(which I have used) , so I am not sure what the problem. I will post If I can find a solution to this.

Comment: So I figured out another way to track the bar progress(html class name was changing to "done 20",40 etc) but dev team made changes to the UI, so I went back in again and while fixing the script I tried the following and it worked- { a.Webelement("css:=.progress-bar-success").Object.currentstyle.backgroundColor}